# User email and password validation

Tags: validation

I have the following code to validate email and password repeat, and keep getting error that "Password does did match" even when I enter the same on form submit. I have the following code. Please help fix as I am new and learning. Simple steps will assist. Thanks in advance.

----html----

```
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>
     <form
          id="userForm"
          action="signup_otp.html"
          class="container"
          method="POST"
          name="userForm"
          onsubmit="return(validate());"
        >
 </body>
```

----script.js---------

```
//Validation of email and password
  function validate() {  
      document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML="";
      var emailVal = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      if(!document.userForm.email_id.value.match(emailVal)) {
          document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML="Enter a valid email format";
          //document.getElementById("email_id").focus();
          document.userForm.email_id.focus();
          //alert(emailAlert);
          return false;
   }
        alert("check passwd")
        document.getElementById("passAlert").innerHTML="";
        var pw1 = document.getElementById("psw");
        var pw2 = document.getElementById("psw_repeat");
      
        console.log(pw1); // console shows null value
        console.log(pw2);

        if(pw1 != pw2)  
        {   
          //alert("Passwords did not match");
          document.getElementById("passAlert").innerHTML="Password did not match"; 
          document.userForm.psw.focus(); 
          return false;
        } else {  
          alert("Password created successfully"); 
          return false;        
        }  
  return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

------script.js

```
 function validate() {  
      document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML="";
      var emailVal = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      if(!document.userForm.email_id.value.match(emailVal)) {
          document.getElementById("emailAlert").innerHTML="Enter a valid email format";
          //document.getElementById("email_id").focus();
          document.userForm.email_id.focus();
          //alert(emailAlert);
          return false;
   }
        //alert("check passwd");
        document.getElementById("passAlert").innerHTML="";
        var pw1 = document.getElementById("psw").value;  
        var pw2 = document.getElementById("psw_repeat").value;
      
        console.log(pw1);
        console.log(pw2);

        if(pw1 != pw2)  
        {   
          //alert("Passwords did not match");
          document.getElementById("passAlert").innerHTML="Password did not match"; 
          document.userForm.psw.focus(); 
          return false;
        } //else {  
          //alert("Password created successfully"); 
          //return false;        
        //}  
  return true;
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
var pw1 = document.getElementById('psw').value
```

Comment: I changed the code, but still not working.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I replaced the code with '''var pw1 = document.getElementById('psw').value''' but still getting the no result, the cod defaults to  error ""Password did not match". The console stil shows value of the variable as 'null'.